# wordpress title and category as result

Tags: plugins

Please have a look a the code below!Its from a WordPress plugin. How can I get the result $search = post title (space ) category name

```
 // Relation: Post title.
if( $relation === 'posttitle' ) {
 global $post;
 $search     = ( isset( $post->post_title ) ) ? $post->post_title : '';
}
```

Its from a WordPress plugin related-youtube-videos. I want to display you tube base on title and category! This plugin has no option for both!

https://wordpress.org/plugins/related-youtube-videos/

related-youtube-videos\lib\RelatedYouTubeVideos\API.php

Comment: Do you have a link to the plugin source?

Comment: I don't suggest you edit anything in the plugin files. When the plugin updates it will overwrite any / all changes you've made.

Comment: the link for the plugin is https://wordpress.org/plugins/related-youtube-videos/

Comment: I know, i wont update the same !